# Make docker-compose run unique linked containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run multiple `docker-compose run` of a container, it creates multiple versions of the main container, but it shares the linked ones.

Is there any way to boot a completely independant container stack for every runs?

Right now I have:

```
$ docker-compose run web &
$ docker-compose run web &
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID     IMAGE      NAMES
a579904eca2d     www_web    www_web_run_2
cb8f07ef0ca4     www_web    www_web_run_1
d3f5e6343200     www_db     www_db_1
```

But I want to have

```
CONTAINER ID     IMAGE      NAMES
a579904eca2d     www_web    www_web_run_2
cb8f07ef0ca4     www_web    www_web_run_1
d3f5e6343200     www_db     www_db_1
d3f5e6343200     www_db     www_db_2
```

Where each web containers get its own DB container.

Comment: Not sure of your particular scenario, but would `docker-composer scale` help here perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `docker-compose` binary help gives an option of:

> -p, --project-name NAME   Specify an alternate project name (default: directory name)

You can do something like:

```
docker-compose -p stack1 up -d
docker-compose -p stack2 up -d
```

Which would give you:

```
stack1_web_1
stack1_db_1
stack2_web_1
stack2_db_1
```

This would allow you to do something like `docker-compose -p stack1 run web cat /etc/os-release` to choose a specific container to work on. It should also preserve links per stack. For example, if you had a link for `db` in the `web` service, `stack1_web_1` would be linked to `stack1_db_1` and `stack2_web_1` would be linked to `stack2_db_1`.

Comment: This is now in the faq as well: https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#how-do-i-run-multiple-copies-of-a-compose-file-on-the-same-host